# A template function and a non-template overload of this function, which is a best match?

Tags: c++, stl, sgi

The code is as follows:

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
inline OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                           OutputIterator result)
{
  return __copy_dispatch<InputIterator,OutputIterator>()(first, last, result);
}

//A overload version
inline char* copy(const char* first, const char* last, char* result) {
  memmove(result, first, last - first);
  return result + (last - first);
}
```

If I call `copy(int*, int*)`, which is the best match, will the compiler instantiate a new function use `int*` as the template parameter, or `int*` will be convert to `char*`.

And what if I call `copy(char[], char[])` notice I just use `char[]` to note the type of parameters.

Comment: The template version since it matches the argumentlist better. Anyway, if two functions have the same signature the one with least templates parameters will be used.

Comment: If you call `copy(int*, int*)` there is no ambiguity: only the template can match. It is easy enough to check that.

Comment: @Xale Is this a general rule that is also suitable for the partial specialization of a template. Because the partial specialization version is always the one that has less template parameters.

Comment: Since no one seems to have mentioned it: `__` in a symbol name is undefined behavior (or at least it was in C++03).

Comment: @JamesKanze This is an excerpt of g++ implementation that only for internal use. And `copy` is the only client interface. :)

Comment: @zoujyjs, Yes, If I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `int *` is not implicitly convertible to `char *` nor to `const char *`, the template function will be called. Removing the template function would result in compile time error.

Suggestion: There is great value in playing around with the compiler yourself. You can add lines like

```
std::cout << "template function called.\n";
```

into your overloads or use the debugger to do that kind of stuff. It's a great learning experience. You might also simply read some C++ books for an introduction.

Comment: Even if the `int*` is implicitly convertible to `char*`, the template version would be instantiated and then invoked. In case of template, the compiler looks for exact match which doesn't require any conversion (implicit or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

> if I call copy(int*, int*), which is the best match,

There in only one match: the template. The version taking `const char*` does not match at all.

> And what if I call copy(char[], char[])

again, the template wins, because the arguments are not `const`. If you did this:

```
const char* c1 = ....;
const char* c2 = ....;
copy(c1, c2);
```

then the non-template would win, because in the case of a perfect overload match, a non-template function takes precedence.

Comment: That's not correct. `char[]` can be converted to `const char *`. But `const char[]` cannot be converted to `char *`.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky it can be converted, but the template will provide a better match, so will win. See [here](http://ideone.com/p6pDh1).

Comment: My gcc compiler complains with `error: call of overloaded function is ambiguous`. I trust gcc here. Did you test it on another compiler?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky I tested on gcc 4.7.3 and a 4.8 snapshot.

Comment: I have a gcc 4.4.6. Has this been a bug? Sorry about this. I take everything back.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky to be honest, I don't know for sure. Everything I said was predicated on the compilers I used being right about this :)